# Landing Page tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I have created a custom page for unsubscribing, where I provide multiple options to choose to unsubscribe from a particular type of email.
For example - 
Category - A 
Category - B 
Category - C 
Category - D 
Category - E
And From ALL.

Backend functionality - 
Once userland on the page, they choose Categories ( Checkbox )  and submit.
I created Different fields on the data extension and changed the value of the domain from False to True. By default, it holds the value False.
When I create the actual data to send the email, I filter by using -
Example - If Category - A  = True Remove the user from that email deployment data extensions.

Now the problem I have that is with the report- 
I am not able to find the number of users what they keep or what categories they choose to unsubscribe.

Question - 
Is there any way I can find and track the total number if a user visits on the landing page?

Is there any way I can track how many users click on the particular checkbox?

Is there any way I can track the particular user visit on the page and unsubscribe from this category, not from this?

any Solution?
Thanks